# A word problem of probability

Tags: probability

Im having a trouble solving this problem for the past hour. Any suggestions would be really great, thank you.

In a box there are white and black balls. If we choose randomly one ball from the box, the probability to be white is 0,3. If in the box we put two more white balls and we choose randomly one ball, the probability to take a white ball in 0,5. Find how many are the white and how many are the black balls in the box.

Comment: Ok....to get started, suppose there are $W$ white and $B$ black.  What does the first bit of information tell you about $W,B$?  What does the second bit of information tell you about $W,B$?

Comment: what i did is P(before) = n(W) / n(B) = 3/10 and P(after) = n(W) + 2 / n(B) + 2 = 1/2

Comment: Well, that's wrong.  Think about it.  Suppose there are $2$ white and $4$ black.  Do you believe that the probability of drawing white is $\frac 24=\frac 12$?

Comment: sorry my mistake.  P(before) = n(W) / n(W + B) = 3/10 and P(after) = n(W) + 2 / n(W + B) + 2 = 1/2

Comment: Ok, so using my notation we have $\frac W{W+B}=.3$ and $\frac {W+2}{W+B+2}=.5$  Can you finish from here?

Comment: thats what i did simple algebra but the result is a fraction. How is that possible

Comment: Please edit your post to show the calculation you did.

Comment: Note:  I agree with you that this does not have integral solutions, so the problem has no solution.

Comment: From the first equation: 10W = 3W + 3 B => 7W = 3B => W = 3B / 7.  From the second equation: 2W + 4 = W + B + 2 =>W - B = -2. And by solving the system i find that B = 7/2

Comment: Yes, I see the only "solution" as $W=\frac 32,B=\frac 72$ which is not physical.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{^WC_1}{^{W+B}C_1}=0.3\implies 7W=3B$$

$$\frac{^{W+2}C_1}{^{W+B+2}C_1}=0.5 \implies W+2=B$$

Solve the equations.